# Is it possible to traverse the Visual Tree of a WPF UIElement using XPath without writing an XPath interpreter?

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, xaml, xpath

I'm currently trying to solve the problem in WPF where the only way to style visual tree elements that aren't exposed as properties of the control (e.g. the overflow button on a toolbar) is to replace the entire template for the control. This seems unwieldy, and requires me to find or write a template a LOT more complex than I currently know how to do.

As part of this, I'm trying to find a maximally flexible way to identify the correct element in the visual tree, ideally one which is capable of queries like "Find the descendant of the element with name 'PART_MyPart' that is a button containing the text 'OK'".

In XPath (operating on imagined XAML) this is pretty easy (leaving aside namespace issues that always seem to crop up when using XPath): `//*[@name='PART_MyPart']//Button[.//TextBlock[@Text='OK']]` (possibly with mistakes - I last used XPath around 6 months back).

The ideal situation I'd like to end up with is XAML that looks like this:

```
<Style TargetType="ToolBar">
    <Style.Resources>
        <local:VisualStyleArgs x:Key="vsargs" VisualElementXPath="//*[@name='PART_MyPart']//Button[.//TextBlock[@Text='OK']]">
            <local:VisualStyleArgs.VisualStyle>
                <Style TargetType="Button">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <!-- Set the template for JUST the visual element here... -->
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </local:VisualStyleArgs>
        </local:VisualStyleArgs>
    </Style.Resources>
    <Setter Property="local:VisualStyle" Value="{x:ref vsargs}" />
</Style>
```

What I think I'm going to end up with instead is XAML that looks like this:

```
<Style TargetType="ToolBar">
    <Style.Resources>
        <local:VisualStyleArgs x:Key="vsargs" >
            <local:VisualStyleArgs.VisualElementFinder>
                 <local:VisualElementFinder Name="PART_MyPart">
                     <local:VisualElementFinder.VisualElementFinder>
                         <local:VisualElementFinder TargetType="Button">
                             <local:VisualElementFinder.VisualElementCondition>
                                 <local:VisualElementFinder TargetType="TextBlock" TargetProperty="Text" TargetValue="OK" />
                             </local:VisualElementFinder.VisualElementCondition>
                         </local:VisualElementFinder TargetType="Button">
                     </local:VisualElementFinder.VisualElementFinder>
                 </local:VisualElementFinder Name="PART_MyPart">
            </local:VisualStyleArgs.VisualElementFinder>
            <local:VisualStyleArgs.VisualStyle>
                <Style TargetType="Button">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <!-- Set the template for JUST the visual element here... -->
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </local:VisualStyleArgs>
        </local:VisualStyleArgs>
    </Style.Resources>
    <Setter Property="local:VisualStyle" Value="{x:ref vsargs}" />
</Style>
```

I can definitely write the second, and I can write a partial XPath interpreter to make it look like the first. But is there a way I can actually query the visual tree with XPath to make the first work with more complex queries?